# User-friendly Property Names in .NET, like those in Rails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

In Ruby on Rails, there's a YAML file in the configuration that lets you define plain-English versions of your model property names. Actually, it lets you define plain-any-language versions: it's part of the internationalization stuff, but most people use it for things like displaying model validation results to the user.

I need that kind of functionality in my .NET MVC 4 project. The user submits a form and gets an email of pretty much everything they posted (the form gets bound to a model). I wrote a helper method to dump out an HTML table of property/value pairs by reflection, e.g.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in obj.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | 
                   BindingFlags.Instance | 
                   BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)) 
{
  if (info.CanRead && !PropertyNamesToExclude.Contains(info.Name)) 
  {
    string value = info.GetValue(obj, null) != null ? 
                                            info.GetValue(obj, null).ToString() :
                                            null;
    html += "<tr><th>" + info.Name + "</th><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

But of course, this prints out `info.Name`'s like "OrdererGid", when maybe "Orderer Username" would be nicer. Is there anything like this in .NET?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a data attribute called DisplayName which allows you to do this. Just annotate your model properties with this and a friendly name for each

```
[DisplayName("Full name")]
public string FullName { get; set; }
```

Comment: And if you need to access that attribute by reflection (as asked for in the question) you'll find it in the [CustomAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.customattributes.aspx) property of the PropertyInfo.

Comment: +1 and if you need more data - you always can create your custom attribute to add more (optional) metadata for each field.

Comment: It's worth adding the `@Html.DisplayFor()` syntax into this answer to indicate how to access it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Much thanks to @Stokedout and @Clemens for the answers. Actually accessing by reflection was a little complicated. For some reason I couldn't access the CustomAttributes property directly. Finally came to this:

```
DisplayNameAttribute dna = (DisplayNameAttribute)info
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();

string name = dna != null ? dna.DisplayName : info.Name;

string value = info.GetValue(obj, null) != null ? 
     (info.GetValue(obj, null).GetType().IsArray ? 
           String.Join(", ", info.GetValue(obj, null) as string[]) : 
           info.GetValue(obj, null).ToString()) : 
      null;

html += "<tr><th>" + name + "</th><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
```